# Testing Twilio Verify

Tags: typescript, testing, twilio

I implemented a Service which hide all of Twilio's wiring, and am trying to write tests for it. I found test credentials etc., but when I try to test my flow, I get this message:

[image]

I'm a little unsure how to actually test the "Verify" flow from Twilio using test credentials. Has anybody done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heyooo. Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

Unfortunately, I have to say that the test credentials only work for specific resources/endpoints right now – meaning buying phone numbers, sending sms and making phone calls.

> Requests to any other resource with test credentials will receive a 403
>   Forbidden response. In the future, we may enable these resources for testing as well.

Only way I see to test the Twilio Helper library in a unit test environment, like the one I see you're going, is to mock the `twilio` module. This way you're not testing Twilio's endpoints but if you're code behaves like it should.

---

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Stefan! Can you tell me whether this is on the roadmap? Or should I just not be testing this way?

Comment: I'll investigate and let you know. :)

Comment: Another Twilio developer evangelist here. I would not recommend writing tests against a remote third party service. Doing so will lead to slow tests (networks are slow) and potentially flaky tests (it requires a network connection). Instead I would look into mocking the HTTP requests (with something like [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock)) or the client library (there's no point testing third party code).

Comment: Hey @stefanjudis, did you get a chance to look into the roadmap? As suggested by your colleague, mocks are a way to go for the testing environment. But what's about end to end testing and staging servers?

Comment: Twilio's how-to articles are great for developing with their APIs, it would be nice to see something of similar quality for doing some testing. I'm pretty new to unit testing and have no idea how to take the advice suggested by you and @philnash (ie mocking the Twilio REST client.)

Comment: @miken32 mocking can be quite different across different libraries and languages and people have strong and sometimes conflicting opinions on it, so it is hard to document with the same rigour as our tutorials. Take a look at the jest documentation on mocking: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules or for a lower level mock, nock: https://github.com/nock/nock. If you can’t write a test that works, then ask a new question here and hopefully someone can help.

Comment: @philnash looking for something for PHP, just happened across this JS question while searching.

Comment: @miken32 I’m afraid I have no experience mocking in PHP, hope you find something!

Comment: A better solution from Twilio would be to provide magic numbers for Verify. Currently they only work for SMS and calls: https://www.reddit.com/r/twilio/comments/kr4ltx/magic_numbers_for_verify/ . We need magic numbers that don't actually send a OTP code, but accept something like 000000 or 111111 etc so that we can run our unit tests without having to mock Twilio. I'd also like to be able to retrieve the sent OTP from within Twilio's admin panel or API, at least for dev environments. This has already caused a few days of head-scratching on my end trying to exercise our website with Puppeteer.